# Write Json File

Tags: json, parsing, vbscript

Ok, so what I want to do is overwrite values in a JSON file based on a regexp match to the name. Example JSON content:

```json
{
"Main": {
    "Modpack": "vanilla",
    "Test1": "Value 1",
    "Test2": "Value 2"
},

"Setup": {
    "Test1": "Value 1",
    "Test2": "Value 2"
},

}
```

And here is the code I am using to get the values:

```vb
Function ParseConfig(File, Key)
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(File, 1)
  Config = objFile.ReadAll

  Dim oRE
  Dim colMatches
  Dim oMatch, I

  Set oRE = New RegExp
  oRE.Global = True
  oRE.IgnoreCase = False
  oRE.Pattern = """" & Key &""":\s""(.+?)"""
  Set colMatches = oRE.Execute ( Config )

  For Each oMatch In colMatches
    strNextmap = oMatch.SubMatches(0)
  Next

  If strNextmap = "" Or IsNull (strNextmap) Then
    ParseConfig = "ERROR:- Config entry not found!"
  Else
    ParseConfig = strNextmap
  End If
  objFile.Close
End Function
```

I call that code with: `ParseConfig ("config", "Modpack")`

How would I modify that code to…

1. Open the file I pass to it for writing
2. Locate the correct value. (I assume I can re-use some of my code here)
3. Replace that value.
4. Save the file.

Comment: JSON is a [type-2 grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). It can't be parsed with via regular expressions (type-3 grammar). You need an actual parser for it.

Comment: It grabs the values though, since the format is "name": "value".
Which is all I needed it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not getting replies and being stubborn really pushes you doesn't it, came up with this solution...

```
Function WriteConfig ( File, Key, Change )

   ' Read file
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( File, 1 )
   Read =   objFile.ReadAll

  ' Find the string
  Set oRE = New Regexp
  oRE.Global = True
  oRE.IgnoreCase = False
  oRE.Pattern = """" & Key &""":\s""(.+?)"""
  Set colMatches = oRE.Execute ( Read )

  For Each oMatch in colMatches
    Match = oMatch.SubMatches(0)
  Next
    Write = Replace ( Read, Match, Change, 1, -1, 0 )

  ' Save the file after modification.
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( File, 2 )
  objFile.Write Write
  objFile.Close

End Function
```

I call it with `WriteConfig "config", "Test1", "Value New"`

Voila! Getting the hang of this VBScript stuff I think...
Just incase anyone is interested here is the read function.

```
'  PARSE JSON  ------------------------ '
Function ParseConfig ( File, Key )
' Example: Modpack = ParseConfig ( "config", "Modpack" )

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( File, 1)
    Config = objFile.ReadAll

    Dim oRE
    Dim colMatches
    Dim oMatch, I

    Set oRE = New Regexp
    oRE.Global = True
    oRE.IgnoreCase = False
    oRE.Pattern = """" & Key &""":\s""(.+?)"""
    Set colMatches = oRE.Execute ( Config )

    For Each oMatch In colMatches
       strNextmap = oMatch.SubMatches(0)
    Next

    If strNextmap = "" Or IsNull (strNextmap) Then
        ParseConfig = "ERROR:- Config entry not found!"
    Else
        ParseConfig = strNextmap
    End If
        objFile.Close
End Function
```